# Does Unity have any automated parameter tuning?

Tags: ai

I have parameters like
-detect enemy range
-firing range
-coverage zone width
-etc.

for a dodgeball game and ideally would like to run the game over and over until I get the highest win rate against an AI opponent (my AI that I froze at an earlier iteration).

This sounds like a neural network problem now, sort of RL-ish except my characters move based on an FSM.

Comment: This sounds like something you could solve in your own script. Write a script that configures these parameters at the start of a match, plays to completion, records the result, modifies the parameters, and repeats. What engine-level support are you looking for to aid with this? [There is an ML Agents package](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents), but that may be more involved than the simple parameter optimization you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory, I'll do that and look into running it from Python?  I've used Bayesian Optimization with success in the past but it was for optimizing a Python program.